# AWS Pre-Signed Post URL suddenly stopped working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

So I have been working with aws-s3 post signed URLs for a month now and it was working as a charm all of sudden( I didn't change any policies for my IAM user or bucket) it start giving me forbidden request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy expired.</Message>
</Error>
```

I found that AWS sent me an email informing me that my trail ended does this has anything to do with it.

Note:I can still upload files to my s3 manually

**Edit**

The code

```
const params = {
    Bucket: 'ratemycourses',
    Fields: {
      key: `profileImage/${userId}/profile.jpeg`,
      acl: 'public-read',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    Expires: 60,
  };
  const data = await s3.createPresignedPost(params) //I made the callback function promisifed;
  return data;
```

Comment: S3 pre-signed urls are temporary. So it seems they expired for you. You have to generate new ones.

Comment: Please show us your code. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Marcin I edited to add the code but I don't think the code is the issue since I didnt change it . it suddenly started to fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expiration element in your POST policy specifies the expiration date/time of the policy. It looks like your policy has expired. Correct the policy expiration, and then re-create your signed URL.

Here's an example of a POST policy:

```
{
    "expiration": "2021-07-10T12:00:00.000Z",
    "conditions": [
        {"bucket": "mybucket" },
        ["starts-with", "$key", "user/shahda/"],
    ]
}
```

Comment: do you mean the policy i gave to the IAM user itself expired?

Comment: No, expired signing credentials would result in a different expiration message. S3 POST requests have an associated [policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html), presented at the time the POST URL is generated.

Comment: Can you check the time synchronization on both the machine generating the URL and the client using the URL?

Comment: Both the frontend(The one that consumes post request) and backend(The one that generates s3 post request) are on my local machine I haven't yet used it in production

Comment: Well, check the POST policy, as mentioned. And be sure to time-sync your machine to NTP.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there's some rules for how long a pre-signed URL is valid: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/presigned-url-s3-bucket-expiration

There's a good amount of details in the link, but in short it depends on the type of user:

- AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) instance profile: Valid up to six hours.
- AWS Security Token Service (STS): Valid up to 36 hours when signed by an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) user, or valid up to one hour when signed by the root user.
- IAM user: Valid up to seven days when using AWS Signature Version 4.

In my case, I was trying to generate a policy with signature that would last for a year, and I suspect the duration made the entire thing invalid.